# Google Data Studio - Can I validate config params on create connector view?

Tags: looker-studio

currently I'm validating my connector's config in `getData` function, but it's not very user-friendly.

```
RequestParamsValidator.prototype.validate = function validate(request) {
  if (!request.configParams || !request.configParams.account_id) {
    ErrorUtils.throwUserError('Account id is required. Please check connector config and try again.');
  }
};
```

Do you know if there's any method (maybe undocumented) of checking e.g. that the value of a field is blank and preventing the user from creating the connector if so?

I checked this reference, but there's nothing about validations:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/text-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the config at the beginning of `getSchema`. This will prevent the user from going past the config screen. Here's an example implementation in the [Kaggle connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/kaggle/src/connector.js#L57).